# Instalar con composer paquetes de github con laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Ante todo saludos.

Necesito instalar el paquete de

> askedio/laravel-soft-cascade

Pero me da error el  composer

`[InvalidArgumentException]Could not find a matching version of package iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).~`

Estoy bajo una conexion medida por proxy, ya lo tengo configurado, no hay problemas y descargo paquetes desde una imagen del repo que hay en mi red, el problema lo da cuando quiero descargar algun paquete fuera del repo local y del oficial, ejemplo desde git.

**¿Cómo puedo descargar ese paquete que puse al principio que esta en https://github.com/Askedio/laravel-soft-cascade?**

Comment: puedes publicar el composer.json que estas usando? yo he utilizado el git clone sobre el repositorio `https://github.com/Askedio/laravel-soft-cascade.git` y me lo ha descargado sin problema...

Comment: No puedo subirlo completo te pongo estos

Comment: "repositories": [
        {
            "packagist": false
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://composer.local.cu"
        },
    ]

Comment: "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "intervention/imagecache": "^2.3",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.5.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.33",
        "spatie/image": "^1.5",
        "spatie/image-optimizer": "^1.1"
    },

Comment: "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente laravel se encuentra en su version 5.8 y tu estas trabajando con su version 5.5, entonces al hacer:

> composer require askedio/laravel-soft-cascade

Te estas descargando la version para laravel 5.8.

**Solucion**

Indica la version del paquete, que como indica el link que dejaste es la `^5.5`

> composer require askedio/laravel-soft-cascade=^5.5

Con eso deberia de quedar solucionado.

Comment: Salio este error [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://api.github.com/repos/Askedio/laravel-soft-cascade" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido.
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido.

Comment: @HugoL, quiza sea la proxi por la te conectas

Comment: ya les puse la configuracion por los http y https y nada, ningun repo fuera del local, ni siquiera clonar desde github , a lo mejor puede ser eso.

Answer (score 1):

**Solucionado**
El problema al descargar era la salida al exterior y el proxy que no permite la descarga de este tipo. Probé desde una conexión libre de proxy y funcionó. Descargué el paquete con este comando `composer require askedio/laravel-soft-cascade "^5.5"` y para usarlo me guié por el sitio https://laraveles.com/como-borrar-y-restaurar-registros-usando-soft-delete-en-laravel/